# Remove consecutive numbers from int array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to remove consecutive repeated numbers from array like  if a sequence of 2 or more instances of the same integer repeated consecutively appears in that array, the sequence should be removed (see example below).

```
int[] array = {3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4};
```

after removal of consecutive repeated numbers

```
(like 1,1 and 4,4,4)=>{3,2,1}
```

thus i want to shift consecutive numbers to end and wanna use `Array.Resize()` function to resize array.
i don't want complete code, approach will be fine.

```
 static void RemoveRepeated(ref int[] array)
    {
        int count = 0; bool flag;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            flag = true;
            for (int j = i+1; j < array.Length-1; j++)
            {
                if (array[i] == array[j] )
                {

                        int temp = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[j + 1];
                        array[j + 1] = temp;
                        if (flag)
                        {
                            count++;
                            flag = false;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        Array.Resize(ref array,array.Length-count);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you just need the unique numbers? You example says so! For that, in C# you can do `array.Distinct();`

Comment: Are you allowed to use Collections ?

Comment: We don't want all your code, the relevant portions will be fine.

Comment: Why must you move the duplicate elements to the end and use resize?

Comment: @ArghyaC  not unique numbers, i want to remove consecutive repeated numbers like 3,3,1,5,5,5,2,3 => 1,2,3

Comment: @PraveenDeewan What you have tried so far ?

Comment: This is no doubt getting down-voted because you're asking for free code without providing any proof that you have tried this yourself. This is not a free coding service, but a place to seek help with code you have already written that perhaps isn't working.

Comment: stop telling us what you want without showing us first what you have tried..? how else do you expect to learn how to code if you do not try something on your own..

Comment: @takendarkk because that's what we can truncate array removing consecutive dup values. we will findout all number of consecutive dups at end and use Array.Resize(ref array,array.Length-numberOfDupsAtEnd)

Comment: please show us @PraveenDeewan can you edit your question and post actual code that you have written to prove your last comment there is no need to use the resize function and even if you do where are you keeping track and or storing what the original values were so that you can do a compare on what you stated with vs what you are yielding ..?

Comment: also you need to clarify if you want all the numbers to be removed if one of them consecutively repeats.. or if you want to remove only one of the numbers if so then even your own example of expected outcome is incorrect..your results should yield `1,2,34` if you were to store in a `List<int>` and populate the array from that sorted list calling the `.ToArray()` method after ..inline..

Comment: @MethodMan i want to  remove sequences of consecutively repeated integers like numbers which come more than 2 times back to back... understood.

Comment: @PraveenDeewan In your example, you want to totally remove {1, 1} and {4, 4, 4} sub sequences, correct?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes right...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that effectively. I think the code is self explanatory.

```
static void RemoveRepeated(ref int[] array)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; )
    {
        var current = array[i];
        int repeatCount = 1;
        while (++i < array.Length && array[i] == current)
            repeatCount++;
        if (repeatCount == 1)
            array[count++] = current;
    }
    Array.Resize(ref array, count);
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked.same code we can use to remove dups across entire array with some modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can push them in a stack one by one, unless the next element in array is equal to the last element in stack.

Comment: @Firat Bakioglu  i have to change in array itself and use Array.Resize which is primary req.

Comment: @PraveenDeewan you need to do your own work stop trying to get someone to do the work for you.. better yet.. go to your instructor and tell them that you do not understand the requirement.. why do you refuse to show us what you have tried..

Comment: @MethodMan i cleared about req may be you are not able to understand me. i want approach not code.

Comment: you are not clear at all and the approach is very simple are you saying that you don't understand how to convert a requirement into actual code..? please edit your question, take the time to think as well as write out what it is you're wanting.. also you need to show us what you have tried on your own.. @PraveenDeewan